# Protoss counter-strategy against another Protoss who mass produces Voidrays?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best counter for Void Rays?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4235/whats-the-best-counter-for-void-rays)

If I am playing as Protoss, how can I counter another Protoss player who mass produces Voidrays?  If I also mass produce Voidrays it's just an arms race; is there a different unit / strategy that is more effective against Voidrays?

Comment: yea but my question is more specifically Protoss VS Protoss

Comment: This is contained in that other question, and indeed the answers there also explain how to counter them as Protoss.